# Digital signature Signer name not showing

Tags: cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, x509certificate, x509certificate2

In C# Why not showing signer name in pdf when signed by Itextsharp library?
I try to crate signed PDF through digital certificate USB Token. When i generate signature on every page that time signature cant show singer name.

Here is the code for getting the certificate:

```
X509Certificate2 certClient = null;
X509Store st = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
string filename = @"..\List1.pdf";
st.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
X509Certificate2Collection collection = st.Certificates;
foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
{                    
    if (cert.Subject.ToLower().Contains("serialnumber"))
    {
        certClient = cert;
        string username = certClient.Subject;
        string startdate = certClient.GetEffectiveDateString();
        string enddate = certClient.GetExpirationDateString();           
    }
}          
st.Close();
IList<X509Certificate> chain = new List<X509Certificate>();
X509Chain x509Chain = new X509Chain();
x509Chain.Build(certClient);
foreach (X509ChainElement x509ChainElement in x509Chain.ChainElements)
{
     chain.Add(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509ChainElement.Certificate));
}
PdfReader inputPdf = new PdfReader(filename);
string dest = @"..\sign10a.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
FileStream os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
appearance.Acro6Layers = false;
appearance.Image = null;
appearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 10, 250, 100), reader.NumberOfPages, null);
IExternalSignature externalSignature1 = new X509Certificate2Signature(certClient, "SHA-256"); 
AllPagesSignatureContainer allPagesContainer = new AllPagesSignatureContainer(appearance, externalSignature1, chain);
MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, allPagesContainer, 8192);
reader.Close();
stamper.Dispose();
```

And here is my multiple appearance  code:

```
public class AllPagesSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    public AllPagesSignatureContainer(PdfSignatureAppearance appearance, IExternalSignature externalSignature, ICollection<X509Certificate> chain)
    {
        this.appearance = appearance;
        this.chain = chain;
        this.externalSignature = externalSignature;
    }

    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
    {
        signDic.Put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS);
        signDic.Put(PdfName.SUBFILTER, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        PdfStamper stamper = appearance.Stamper;
        PdfReader reader = stamper.Reader;
        PdfDictionary xobject1 = new PdfDictionary();
        PdfDictionary xobject2 = new PdfDictionary();
        xobject1.Put(PdfName.N, appearance.GetAppearance().IndirectReference);
        xobject2.Put(PdfName.AP, xobject1);
        PdfIndirectReference PRef = stamper.Writer.PdfIndirectReference;
        PdfLiteral PRefLiteral = new PdfLiteral((PRef.Number + 1 + 2 * (reader.NumberOfPages - 1)) + " 0 R");

        for (int i = 1; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            var signatureField = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(stamper.Writer);
            signatureField.Put(PdfName.T, new PdfString("ClientSignature_" + i.ToString()));
            signatureField.Put(PdfName.V, PRefLiteral);
            signatureField.Put(PdfName.F, new PdfNumber("132"));
            signatureField.SetWidget(appearance.Rect, null);
            signatureField.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.WIDGET);
            signatureField.Put(PdfName.AP, xobject1);
            signatureField.SetPage();
            Console.WriteLine(signatureField);

            stamper.AddAnnotation(signatureField, i);
        }
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
    {
        String hashAlgorithm = externalSignature.GetHashAlgorithm();
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, false);
        IDigest messageDigest = DigestUtilities.GetDigest(hashAlgorithm);
        byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, hashAlgorithm);
        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        byte[] extSignature = externalSignature.Sign(sh);
        sgn.SetExternalDigest(extSignature, null, externalSignature.GetEncryptionAlgorithm());
        return sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);            
    }
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance;
    ICollection<X509Certificate> chain;
    IExternalSignature externalSignature;
}
```

Digital signature show multiple page but signer name can't display.

[image]

I hope it helps, I wrote the code from examples which found on internet. it will work but only singer name not display.

Comment: Don't you need to call `setFieldName` of the `appearance`? Just guessing here. Could also be that the Common Name (CN) in the cert is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wonder why in your visualization

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMC0P.png]

there is no name after "Digitally signed by".

iTextSharp creates that text line like this:

```c#
buf.Append("Digitally signed by ");
String name = null;
CertificateInfo.X509Name x500name = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields((X509Certificate)signCertificate);
if (x500name != null) {
    name = x500name.GetField("CN");
    if (name == null)
        name = x500name.GetField("E");
}
if (name == null)
    name = "";
buf.Append(name).Append('\n');
```

*(excerpt from `PdfSignatureAppearance.GetAppearance()`)*

`signCertificate` here is the BouncyCastle `X509Certificate` otherwise accessible via the `PdfSignatureAppearance` property `Certificate`.

But in your code you do not set that `appearance.Certificate` property. Thus, in the code above `x500Name` is `null`. Consequentially `name` is `""` and no name is added after `"Digitally signed by "`.

If you want that field to be automatically filled in by iText, therefore, provide the necessary information and set `appearance.Certificate`. Alternatively you can generate the appearance yourself.